# I have 32 bit python and 32 bit WMI module installed but wmi returns an error

Tags: python, wmi

I installed wmi with the installer here http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html
but I can't get the module to import.

Here is my code:

```
import wmi

c=wmi.WMI()

for os in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
    print(os.Caption)
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/Programs/WMI trial.py", line 1, in <module>
  import wmi
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 88, in <module>
  from win32com.client import GetObject, Dispatch
ImportError: No module named 'win32com'
```

Any idea why this isn't working? I have a 64 bit system but that hasn't affected running 32 bit python at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the 'Python For Windows Extensions' (pywin32).

WMI module requires [pywin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/).

run the appropriate installer for pywin32, then try WMI again.

The "No module named 'win32com'" error is because it can't find the winm32com module (which is installed as part of pywin32 package.)

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Unfortunately I won't be able to test this until Sunday night/Monday. If it works then I'll mark this as the answer!

Comment: I downloaded the pywin extension and it still wouldn't work, albeit with a different error. I had to move the api file to the main python folder and then it started working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:
i downloaded the source named: `WMI-1.4.9.zip` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/
Extracted all files from that zip file and saved it in a folder named: `WMI-1.4.9` and then copied that folder to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
After that I navigated to that folder C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\WMI-1.4.9 and did a shift + right click -> Open Command line here and ran: `python setup.py install`

That's it, after that it worked for me like charm. No issues.

p.s - While installing exe I had some weird Access Denied errors, I tried by running the exe as Administrator even then I could get through it. Hence that didn't at all work for me.

Edit:
Also I had pywin32 installed from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/ (select the correct file - 'bittedness' and python version wise)